# How allow my app to POST a cloudfunction in firebase that makes another POST?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying a react app that consumes firebase functions, here my code:

```html
handleDonate(key){
        const url = 'https://us-central1-bora-ajudar-73ebc.cloudfunctions.net/api/donate'
        const dados = {teste : 'oi'} 
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'},
            data : dados,
            url
        }
        axios(options)
        .then(data=>{
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
```

Then, my index.js function

```html
app.use(cors({origin: true}));

admin.initializeApp()

const checkoutUrl = 'https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout/payment.html?code='

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))


app.get('/api', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('Server side')
})

app.post('/donate',(req,res)=>{
    request({
        uri: 'https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout?',
        method: 'POST',
        form:{
            token: token,
            email: email,
            currency: 'BRL',
            itemId1: 'idCampanha',
            itemDescription1: 'Doação',
            itemQuantity1: '1',
            itemAmount1: '2.00'
        },
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-urlencode; charset=UTF8',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'true'
        }
    })
    .then(data=>{
        parse(data, (err,json)=>{
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'true')
            res.send({
                url: checkoutUrl+json.checkout.code[0]
            })
        })
    })
    
})
```

When i run it, console shows this error:

> Failed to load https://us-central1-bora-ajudar-73ebc.cloudfunctions.net/api/donate: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://bora-ajudar-73ebc.firebaseapp.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I know that is something about sending POST to my function and my function sending another POST, but i dont know exactly what.

Comment: The 500 status of the response is the problem you need to solve. The cause has nothing at all to do with CORS. That console message is just telling you that it can’t expose the response to your frontend code because it doesn’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: Thanks for advise. Tried setting the header, but it dont worked :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that firebase don't allow external API requests in free plan.